# What does it mean for a well ordering to have length ω? ω^ω?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

From what I understand, an ordinal is the position of an element in a set. For example, in [2,4,6....] the element [4] has ordinal 2 (please correct me if I'm wrong).

What does it mean to have ordinal ω? Is this the ordinal of infinity?

What is the meaning of ω^ω?

Comment: Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number.

Comment: See [Intuition for $\omega^\omega$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336373/intuition-for-omega-omega).

Answer (score 4):

There's some confusion going on here about what an ordinal is, so let me start at the beginning.

A *linear order* is a set $S$ together with a binary relation on $S$, $\prec$, with some reasonable properties:

- **(transitivity)** $a\prec b$ and $b\prec c$ implies $a\prec c$; and
- **(trichotomy)** For all $a, b\in S$, exactly one of the following holds:

  - $a\prec b$;
  - $b\prec a$; or
  - $a=b$.

Some examples of linear orders include $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{N}$ with the usual orderings, but there are other weird ones too (like the [Sharkovskii order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharkovskii%27s_theorem), an important object in dynamical systems theory).

Now, amongst all linear orders, we're interested in the ones with a particular property: *well-orderedness*.

> A linear order $(S, \prec)$ is *well-ordered* if it has no infinite descending sequence $s_0\succ s_1\succ s_2\succ . . .$; equivalently, if every nonempty subset of $S$ has a $\prec$-least element.

For instance, the naturals are well-ordered, but the integers, the rationals, and the reals (with the usual orderings anyways) are not.

The interest in well-orders mainly comes from the fact that they support **proof by induction**:

> Exercise: suppose $(S, \prec)$ is a well-order, and $P$ is some property of elements of $S$ such that $P(s)$ holds whenever $\forall t\prec s(P(t))$. Then $P(s)$ holds for all $s\in S$. *HINT: consider the set $\{s: \neg P(s)\}$. . .*

Now it turns out that well-orderings "look like $\mathbb{N}$ with stuff at the end." For example, consider the ordering on the naturals we get by "moving $1$ to the front": $$2\prec 3\prec 4\prec . . . \prec 1.\quad (\forall m, n\in\mathbb{N}[m\prec n\iff 1<m<n \mbox{ or } n=1, m\not=1]).$$ This is also a well-ordering (exercise).

Now let's go back to ordinals. One usage of ordinals is to name terms in a sequence; that's the one you mention in the OP. In set theory, though, the more common usage is to name the *shape* (or *order type*) of a sequence. What do I mean by that? Well, $$2, 1, -117$$ has three terms - I'm going to say it has order-type $3$. Similarly, $$1, 2, 3$$ has order-type $3$.

"$\omega$" is the symbol we use to describe the order type of $$1\prec 2\prec 3\prec . . .,$$ that is, of the natural numbers with the usual ordering. Now here's the fun bit: what is the order type of the well-order $2\prec 3\prec 4\prec . . . \prec 1$ described above?

Well, consider the map $f: x\mapsto x+1$. This gives an order-preserving bijection from the naturals with their usual order, to this weird order *except $1$*. Basically, this new well-order has ordertype . . . $\omega+1$!

We can make longer and longer well-orderings. For example, the order type of $$1\prec 3\prec 5\prec 7\prec . . . \prec 2\prec 4\prec 6\prec 8\prec . . . .$$ is $\omega+\omega$.

This should hopefully give some intuition behind what ordinals (= order-types of well-orderings) are doing. I've stopped short of [ordinal exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation), but I think getting a good grounding in what ordinals mean, intuitively, is more important at first.

Answer (score 2):

To be precise an ordinal number is an equivalence class defined on well-ordered sets where two are equivalent if and only if there exists an ordering preserving **bijection** between them.

These ordinal numbers are ordered themselves: ordinal number $x$ is lower then ordinal number $y$ if and only if there exists an ordering preserving **injection** between some members of corresponding equivalence classes. Thus we can order ordinal numbers and there's a theorem stating that every set of ordinal numbers is well ordered. Thus it produces an ordinal number as well.

Examples:

1. $[\emptyset]$ is the smallest ordinal
2. $[\emptyset] < [\{1\}]$ and there's nothing between them
3. $[\emptyset] < [\{1\}] < [\{1 < 2\}]$ and there's nothing between them
4. $[\emptyset] < [\{1\}] < [\{1 < 2\}] < [\{1 < 2 < 3\}]$ and there's nothing between them

and so on. Brackets $[]$ denote "equivalence class" and note that $<$ inside brackets $[]$ denotes how the sets are ordered and external $<$ denotes how those well-ordered sets are related to each other.

By convenience we use the same symbol for numbers and finite ordinals, i.e.

$$0 := [\emptyset]$$
$$n := [\{1 < \cdots < n\}]$$

Now the interesting thing is when you hit infinity. Note that if you take the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = \{1 < 2 < 3 < \cdots\}$ then it is bigger then **any** finite set. In particular

$$[\{1 < \cdots < n\}] < [\mathbb{N}]$$

And it can be shown that $\mathbb{N}$ is the smallest ordinal with this property. This ordinal was named omega:

$$\omega := [\mathbb{N}]$$

In particular we have a sequence of ordinals:

$$(0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < \cdots) < \omega$$

But here's something interesting: we can increase that set (in the sense of well ordering, the cardinality doesn't change). Consider $X = \mathbb{N}\cup \{\alpha\}$ where $\alpha$ is just a symbol (element not in $\mathbb{N}$) and define $\alpha > n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This set is bigger then $\mathbb{N}$ and actually it defines the very next ordinal after $\omega$, denoted $\omega + 1$.

This construction can go on so you get $\omega+2, \omega+3, \ldots$ and by going to the limit (the idea similar to the one above) we get $\omega\cdot 2 = \omega+\omega$.

This construction goes on as well so you get $\omega\cdot 2, \omega\cdot 3,\omega\cdot 4, \ldots$ and now by going to the limit we obtain $\omega^{2}$.

Again we can repeat the construction: $\omega^{3}, \omega^{4}, \ldots$ and by taking a limit we finally arrive at $\omega^{\omega}$.

Note that this is not the end. The construction can be extended even further to $\omega^{\omega^{\omega}}, \omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\omega}}}, \ldots$ without ever reaching the end of those (which is beyond the size of any set).

Comment: +1, but a slight quibble: your last paragraph makes it sound like every ordinal is less than some finite tower of $\omega$s. This isn't true; see e.g. [$\epsilon_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)). More generally, each of these ordinals is countable; there are uncountable ordinals! The correct statement is that the collection of all ordinals does not form a set, but the sequence suggested by $\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega}, . . . $ is a tiny, tiny start to this.

Comment: @NoahSchweber To be 100% precise the statement `there are uncountable ordinals` is true under the Axiom of Choice. Without it I'm not so sure.

Comment: What I wrote was already $100\%$ precise. It does not involve the axiom of choice at all. It follows immediately from powerset, separation, and the axiom of infinity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number. Indeed, the only thing Choice does is say that every set can be put into bijection with some ordinal, which is irrelevant here.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402493/what-set-theory-axioms-do-i-need-to-believe-in-uncountable-ordinals.

Comment: @Noah Schweber: To add to what Noah said, getting to the epsilon numbers and even well beyond (the $\epsilon_{0}$'th $\epsilon$ number, the $\epsilon_{0}$'th entry in the transfinite sequence of $\epsilon_{0}$'th $\epsilon$ numbers, and way, way beyond this) does not require an uncountable ordinal, let alone the axiom of choice.

Comment: To add to what @DaveL.Renfro said (:P), the way you do this is as follows: suppose $f$ is any increasing function on countable ordinals such that (1) $\alpha\le f(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$, and (2) $\sup_{i\in I}(f(\alpha_i))=f(\sup_{i\in I}(\alpha_i))$ (this latter condition is called *continuity*). Then $f$ has a *club* of fixed points, $f(\beta)=\beta$. (To prove that the set of fixed points of $f$ is unbounded, fix $\gamma<\omega_1$ and let $\beta=\sup\{\gamma, f(\gamma), f(f(\gamma)), . . .\}$.) This gives us [some big countable ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function).

Comment: Note that as long as $f$ is "reasonable," even this will not get you beyond [the first noncomputable ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Kleene_ordinal), which is countable.

Comment: To add to the fun @Noah Schweber and I are having, note that "the $\epsilon_0$'th entry in the transfinite sequence of $\epsilon_0$'th $\epsilon$ numbers" is $\epsilon_{\epsilon_{\epsilon_0}},$ which is way, way less than the first fixed point of the normal function (increasing and continuous function from ordinals to ordinals) that enumerates the $\epsilon$ numbers, which as far as normal functions are concerned, is one of the tamest.